# How to add limit_req zone for a particular location in nginx ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, rate-limiting

I have an ingress something like below

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: staging-ingress-rules-login
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: 'nginx'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: '0'
spec:
  rules:
  - host: staging.mysite.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: login
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /login/info
        backend:
          serviceName: login
          servicePort: 80
```

and the nginx.conf for this is something like this

```
server { 
 location / {
   ---------
   ---------
}

location /login/info {
  ---------
  -------
}

}
```

I would like to add the rate limit for location /login.info, i tried location-snippet but it is creating nested location inside /login/info and the result for this api is giving 404, any way to do this ?

Comment: Could you share the location-snippets you tried by editing your question?

Comment: location ~* ^/login/info\/?(?<baseuri>.*) {
       limit_req zone=one;
}

Comment: Could you edit your question so we can see how you formatted syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer, feel free to edit and expand it.

As we are lacking some details regarding your configuration, I will explain how you can deal with this in general.

You can use the below annotation in order to add a custom location block:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  limit_req zone=authentication_ratelimit nodelay;
```

And than use a **map**, for example:

```
http-snippets: |
  map $uri $with_limit_req {
    default 0;
    "~*^/authenticate$" 1;
  }
  map $with_limit_req $auth_limit_req_key {
    default '';
    '1'     $binary_remote_addr; # the limit key
  }
  limit_req_zone $auth_limit_req_key zone=authentication_ratelimit:10m rate=1r/s;
```

[Notice that](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html#limit_req_zone):

> ```
> Syntax:   limit_req_zone key zone=name:size rate=rate [sync];
> Default:  —
> Context:  http
> ```
>
> Sets parameters for a shared memory zone that will keep states for
> various keys. In particular, the state stores the current number of
> excessive requests. The key can contain text, variables, and their
> combination. Requests with an empty key value are not accounted.